# Magento 2: Updating product Price & Quantity Automatically

Tags: magento2

I tried to do Updating product Price & Quantity Automatically, 
I have created [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10YGvXCeYkgTI3POPViXP7I5-unJzHlfj) Module in my Local System.

- connected to Oracle Database with OCI in php
- Getting details from table and updating price & Quantity of product based on SKU.
- Saving Order Details back into My Oracle Database.

Now, I'm not able to figure out how to can connect to Database from server.

I heard that it is possible by consuming Web services, Please let me know how I can be achieved.

Please let me know that is the best way to manage the Fluctuating Price & Quantity in e-commerce world when dealing with magento in perticular.

Let me know if you need any more details, Thanks in advance.

Comment: so your issue is basically 'How to connect Oracle database with the server/ magento2'?